# SciKit Learn - Bad SGDClassifier accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to model some data with SGDClassifier, but for some reason I get horrible accuracy. I'm quite new to this, so I don't really understand why.

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics as ms

msk = np.random.rand(len(beers)) < 0.8

train = beers[msk]
test = beers[~msk]

X = train [['Price', 'Net price', 'Purchase price','Hour','Product_id','product_group2']]
y = train[['Quantity']]
y = y.as_matrix().ravel()

X_test = test [['Price', 'Net price', 'Purchase price','Hour','Product_id','product_group2']]
y_test = test[['Quantity']]
y_test = y_test.as_matrix().ravel()

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)  
X = scaler.transform(X)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test) 

clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", alpha=0.01, n_iter=1000, fit_intercept=True)
clf.fit(X, y)    

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
print "Accuracy:", ms.accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
```

The accuracy printed is around 0.38, which is really bad. My data looks like this:

```
    Product_id/Date/product_group1/Price/Net price/Purchase price/Hour/Quantity/product_group2/KPI
0   107 12/31/2012  10  300 236 220 10  1   108 16
```

And I have 200 000+ lines of data.

What else should I do? The data is scaled, so that shouldn't be a problem, and the model should also converge after 1000 iterations.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your data is just hard to predict.  What makes you think you should be able to get higher accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GridSearchCV to optimize the parameters of your SGD Classifier.
Also go through sklearn.feature_selection to get the best features.